# Font weight of text changes in a fixed div when it scrolls over flash or jquery google maps, why and what to do about it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, flash, fonts

A while ago I made a fixed div as a navigation menu for a page. I noticed that the text's font-weight decreased when it scrolled over a vimeo flash movie.

Now I am seeing it again in another navigation menu, but this time while scrolling over a jquery google map: http://jorenfrielink.com/beta/

As you can see the menu button's font-weight decreases when it overlays the map. So far I've noticed this in chrome and safari.

Is this a common problem and what is there to do about it?

Comment: I can't replicate it from this PC. Are you on a PC or Mac?

Comment: I'm using chrome and I don't see what you're describing.

Comment: That's weird. My exact user agent is: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4. My tablet doesn't seem to do this either..

Comment: won't reproduce on Chromium 20.x, running on a Linux, Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: To show you what i mean; It's supposed to be this: http://jorenfrielink.com/dump/01.png. On the map it's this: http://jorenfrielink.com/dump/02.png

Answer (score 8):

Something is causing your font smoothing to change, things like css3 animations or transforms can cause that. Try adding this to your navigation text:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. On the other hand, -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; did!

Thanks for your input!

Comment: I had my text in a div with fixed position and subpixel antialiasing worked! thanks.

Comment: I had google fonts showing different weights on pages that scrolled vs didn't scroll. This fixed it.

Comment: Worked for me on both Safari 7.1 and Chrome 41

Answer (score 4):

As Joren mentioned:
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

This worked in Chrome + Safari

Answer (score 2):

Try this fix:

`opacity: 99;`

on the text.

If this fixes it, then your problem stems from the way OSX renders fonts. It was optimized for dark text on a light background, so there's that weird bold effect when you reverse it. This opacity trick is a workaround that makes it display in a standard manner, even if it's light-on-dark.